# Scan text and replace if matched

Tags: java, android, if-statement, for-loop

Could you tell me what is wrong with my `for` loop below? I want the program to scan all the words in the text and check them - if found that it matches one of a set of words it replace it.  For example, if the sentence in the text is "nona chan" i want it to scan word by word and if it finds the word 'nona' replace with the word 'good', then go on to the next word.

```
package com.example.split;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        final EditText te1 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t1);
        final EditText te2 = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.t2);

        final Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.b1);
        b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                //imva.setImageResource(R.id.b1);

                String t = te1.getText().toString();
                String[] t1 = t.split(" ");
                for (int i = 0; i <= t1.length; i++) {

                    do {
                        if (t1[i].equals("nona")) {
                            String v1 = t1[i];
                            String v2 = " good  ";
                            String a = v1.replace(v1, v2);
                            te2.setText(a);
                        } else if (t1[i].equals("chan")) {
                            String v1 = t1[i];
                            String v3 = " job  ";
                            String a = v1.replace(v1, v3);
                            te2.setText(a);
                        }
                    } while (te1.length() != 0);
                }

            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Change i<= t1.length to i<t.length

Answer (score 2):

You're exceeding the array bounds. replace

```
for (int i = 0 ; i<= t1.length ; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < t1.length ; i++)
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Reimeus' answer and @Pragnani's comment which are both correct that your `for()` loop exceeds the array length by 1...

Remove the `do/while` loop because it will always be looped infinitely and hang your app!
Replace then loop with its contents.

---

Also, this line does not do anything:

```
String a =  v1.replace(v1, v2);
```

Is simply installs `v2` into `a`, so it can be replaced with:

```
String a = v2;
```

Comment: thenks alot for telling me :) i deleted it